# System.Convert.ToDouble(decimal) giving two different answers

Tags: c#, precision, managed-directx

I've got a very odd issue. I run this in the immediate window:

```cs
?(System.Convert.ToDouble(2458963.229671001113318401517D))

2458963.229671001
```

Which is what I expect!

Then, later on in my application, after initializing Managed DirectX, I get the following:

```cs
?(System.Convert.ToDouble(2458963.229671001113318401517D))

2458963.25
```

After I hit that point in my code, forever after `System.Convert.ToDouble()` will return truncated and wrong results.

I've isolated the single line that causes this change in `System.Convert.ToDouble()` behavior:

```cs
new Device(adapterOrdinal, dType, this, flags, m_presentParams);
```

Which is a `Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Device` object, from:

```
// Assembly: Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D, Version=1.0.2902.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```

I'm not sure why creating a `Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Device` causes a change in how `System.Convert.ToDouble()` acts.

Comment: BTW, MDX was deprecated a looong time ago, before XNA (also abandoned by MS)

Comment: Use [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) or [SlimDX](https://github.com/SlimDX/slimdx), not legacy Managed DirectX. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-and-net/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb324030(v%3Dvs.85):

> When a Device object is created, the common language runtime will
>   change the floating-point unit (FPU) to single precision to maintain
>   better performance. To maintain the default double precision FPU,
>   which is default for the common language runtime, use the
>   CreateFlags.FpuPreserve flag when creating a Device object

Comment: Thank you, that looks like it. We've been calling this issue "the curse".... You have lifted it.

Comment: _I learnt something new today_. I haven't seem something this bad since the in-place replacement of .NET 4 with 4.5

Comment: Note this floating-point CRT behavior of Direct3D is unique to legacy Direct3D 9 and prior. Back in the day, a lot of vertex processing was done on the CPU so it made a big difference. Today, it's mostly hardware processing or specialized CPU hardware. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/top-issues-for-windows-titles#manipulation-of-the-floating-point-control-word)